# SVG group moved by draggable textarea over it

Tags: javascript, svg, drag

**What is my situation:**

1. I have an svg (1024x576) which is displayed on website with width 818px and height 458px
2. Over group #levapostava is absolutely positioned textarea and is draggable (over svg)
3. When textarea is being dragged so is #levapostava by changing matrix

**What is my problem:**

When I drag my textarea (absulute position) by 10px to the left I need to know how many pixels to the left should be #levapostava moved since view-box is 1024x576 and svg is displayed 818x458px. It is not 10px due to translation.

I just lost 4 hours trying to figure this one out but no success.

**Thank you for any suggestion!**

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="576px" viewBox="0 0 1024 576" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 576" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <g id="levapostava" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)">
               ...
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>

    <textarea which is absolutely positioned over #levapostava />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the function `getScreenCTM()` on the SVG element will give you the matrix used to convert an SVG point to a screen coordinate.  But you want the other way round, so you need to invert that matrix by calling `inverse()` on it.

Now if you run a screen point through the matrix, you will get the equivalent point in the SVG.  You can use that to transform the "levapostava" group.

Your code will look something like:

```
// Get the SVG dom element
var  svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

// Get an SVGPoint object that we can transform
var screenPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
screenPoint.x = textareaLeft;
screenPoint.y = textareaTop;

// Get the Current Transform Matrix of the SVG, and invert it
var inverseCTM = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();

// Apply the inverted transform to the (textarea) screen coordinates
var svgPoint = screenPoint.matrixTransform(inverseCTM);
// 'svgPoint' is now the point in the SVG space that corresponds to
// screenPoint in screen space

// Apply a transform the SVG object to match the textarea
var levapostava = svg.getElementById("levapostava");
levapostava.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + svgPoint.x + "," + svgPoint.y + ")");
```